# Red Triangle notification on top panel

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, ppa

I have a red triangle on the top panel that says
`The update information is outdated. This may be caused by network problems or by a repository that is no longer available. Please update manually by selecting show updates from the indicator menu and watching for any failing repositories.`

My Ubuntu is up to date. It takes time to appear after turning on laptop and it always returns even though Ubuntu is up-to-date.

Output of `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libbit-vector-perl libcarp-clan-perl libclass-method-modifiers-perl
  libdata-random-perl libdate-calc-perl libdate-calc-xs-perl libgd-perl
  libgnome2-gconf-perl libmouse-perl libnet-dropbox-api-perl
  linux-headers-3.13.0-32 linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

and here's output of `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Ign http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring InRelease                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Ign http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg                          
Ign http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring Release                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:1 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B]          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages                  
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/restricted amd64 Packages            
Get:2 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [62.0 kB]            
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages              
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse amd64 Packages            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages             
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages               
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release                      
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en              
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Get:3 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [152 kB]        
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_IE               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_IE                     
Get:4 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [2,061 B] 
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_IE         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:5 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [96.5 kB]   
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_IE         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_IE                     
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_IE           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:6 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [3,543 B] 
Get:7 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [392 kB] 
Get:8 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [8,875 B]
Get:9 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [236 kB]
Get:10 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [9,370 B]
Get:11 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [384 kB] 
Get:12 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [8,846 B]
Get:13 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [237 kB]
Get:14 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [9,553 B]
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Ign http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IE                 
Ign http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_IE           
Ign http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_IE           
Ign http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_IE             
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       

Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg                     
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      

Err http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
  Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
Err http://linux.dropbox.com trusty InRelease                           

Err http://linux.dropbox.com trusty Release.gpg                         
  Could not resolve 'linux.dropbox.com'
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'
Fetched 1,602 kB in 40s (39.9 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'linux.dropbox.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Have you checked your network? You can't update with a non-working/slow network.

Comment: yes, network is fine. I have managed to get rid of it now but it will return tomorrow or if I restart machine

Comment: Can your browser resolve: http://extras.ubuntu.com/ and http://security.ubuntu.com ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, If you mean open in the browser, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red sign notes update problems. Second log shows the problems getting repository updates ("Some index files failed to download" and especially "Could not resolve").

### Possible causes and solutions

*(From most to less probable.)*

- Name lookup problems

  - Current DNS server failing

    **Solution:** Use another server (eg. Google's DNS servers: IPs 8.8.4.4 and 8.8.8.8)
  - Hosts file modified

    **Solution:** Check file `/etc/hosts` for lines containing "google", "dropbox", "ubuntu". If they are - cleanup these lines (or replace file with initial clean version)
- Internet connection broken

  - Internet provider

    **Solution:** Try to use another ISP
  - Network adapter performing unstable

    **Solution:** Try to use another adapder (switch to wireless network from wired or vice versa; plug in another adapter, eg. USB one)
  - Malware infection

    **Solution:** Perform malware check, preferably offline.

In the most cases it's DNS server problems.